# How do You Prevent Texture Light Washout When Using Bright HDRs?

Tags: texturing, materials, light, hdri

I have been having a lot of trouble preventing textures from getting washed out when getting hit with even a moderate amount of light. It keeps making my scenes look fake and poorly rendered and I wish there was an easy way to correct this. This is what my demo scene looks like in the material preview where it looks perfect.
[image]

This is what my demo scene looks like in the render preview where it looks washed out.
[image]

Here is a link to the demo Blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10cTD3O4WKq4uBi7em7TMG1LWXbwfB1El/view?usp=sharing

Is there any way that I can darken the texture while still preserving the majority of the texture's attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to keep the background image the same brightness, but want a different strength for the light it provides, you can mix Backgrounds of different strengths (or even different images) using a Mix Shader and the *Is Camera Ray* output of a Light Path node. This splits the background between its image and its cast light and reflections so they can be controlled independently:

[image: BackgroundStr]